# Mathematica PCA biplot

Tags: plotting

Using Wolfram Mathematica, how can I plot a PCA biplot as in the following figure?

[image: PCA biplot]

Comment: It's just a scatter plot of the PC1 vs. PC2 scores; it's not too difficult. The only tricky part of it, I think, is making the two differently scaled axes for the samples and the variables coincident, but you can just superimpose two separate plots if necessary. What aspect of it is giving you difficulty?

Comment: You must make a plot for the variables and a plot for the objects. Your plot is not correct, because the two spaces are not the same
André

Comment: Can you include a small example data set that we could work from to try and produce a plot? If you edit the question, you can ask for it to be reopened. I, for one, find yours to be an interesting question that may have useful answers.

Comment: @Andre It's not correct? Are you sure? [biplot](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/stats/html/biplot.princomp.html)